# Prove that $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is continuous at $a=(3,\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I'm seriously struggling with understanding how to do these problems.

I start with the theorem:

---

$\forall\,\epsilon >0,\ \exists\,\delta>0$ s.t.

$d[(x,y),(c,d)] < \delta$ $\implies$ $d(f(x,y), f(c,d)) < \epsilon$

---

I know the above is just the general theorem but I think it's good to have visible.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What does $a = (3,{1 \over 2})$ have to do with anything?

Comment: One moment. I made a mistake. I had moved to a diferent problem and copied my work from that down. My apologies.

Comment: So then fix it!!!

Comment: There I have fixed it.

Comment: No you haven't.  In the title you're saying that $a$ is a two-dimensional point  but in the body it is a scalar.  And why do you need that point in the title anyway?  It is arbitrary and doesn't help anyone find or solve your problem.  Also, the title itself is vague and unclear otherwise.

Comment: I am given exactly, "Prove that the functions are continuous at a. Then I am given the function as in the title and I am given a as in the title. Is what I have in this comment not clearly expressed in my title? If so please let me know. I'm not trying to be confusing.

Comment: Oh I see where the confusion came from. I meant the theorem I added as a general theorem and not for the a provided. I will change it so it's not as confusing. I just meant that this was the definition I felt was correct to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The so-called "theorem" is indeed a definition which goes as follows:
$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous in $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ if there for any $\epsilon>0$ exists a $\delta>0$ such that for any $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with  $d((x,y),(a,b))<\delta$ then $d(f(x,y),f(a,b))<\epsilon$.

Now to show that $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is indeed continuous everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^2$, we first fix an arbitrary $(a,b)$ and $\epsilon>0$. Note that $f$ is indeed the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so we can use the reverse triangle inequality. For any $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with $|(x,y)-(a,b)|<\delta=\epsilon$ \begin{align}
d(f(x,y),f(a,b))&=|f(x,y)-f(a,b)| \\
&= |\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}|\\
&= |\, |(x,y)| - |(a,b)|\, | \\
&\leq |(x,y)-(a,b)| \\
&< \epsilon,
\end{align}
proving that $f$ is continuous in $(a,b)$ and since this was arbitrarily chosen we conclude that $f$ is everywhere continuous. This obviously assumes that both domain and co-domain of $f$ are equipped with the corresponding Euclidean metrics.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My only question is, how do you go from $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ to $|(x,y)|$?

Comment: @Nicklovn The norm of $(x,y)$, denoted here by $|(x,y)|$ is by definition $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, so your function is just the norm itself that we use to measure Euclidean distance.

Comment: I assumed that you have been introduced to the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ before talking about continuity of mappings from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Usually when we talk about continuity on Euclidean spaces we equip them with the Euclidean norm given by $|(x_1,...,x_n)| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}$ for $(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Oh I understand. Thank you. Yes I am a little behind on this material. I'm a stats major and skipped the 200-level real analysis course so I'm just trying to stay up there with everyone else :)